# Route through ppp0?

Tags: network-interface, routing, networkmanager, vpn, tunneling

read carefully pls..
im connecting to another local network IN (overWAN) using q vpn (openfortivpn) to access that local network.

i can ping the local hosts on that network.. i can scan em with nmap and everything work perfectly.
but the problem is when i use metasploit it seems like it doesnt reconize em (local hosts on that network) even tho i changed metasploit network interface..
so whats the problem in here..any ideas!!!

```
    └─$ sudo openfortivpn            
[sudo] password for redandwhite: 
INFO:   Connected to gateway.
INFO:   Authenticated.
INFO:   Remote gateway has allocated a VPN.
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
INFO:   Got addresses: [192.168.10.20], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
INFO:   Negotiation complete.
INFO:   Got addresses: [192.168.10.20], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
INFO:   Negotiation complete.
INFO:   Got addresses: [192.168.10.20], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
INFO:   Negotiation complete.
INFO:   Negotiation complete.
local  IP address 192.168.10.20
remote IP address 169.254.2.1
INFO:   Interface ppp0 is UP.
INFO:   Setting new routes...
INFO:   Adding VPN nameservers...
INFO:   Tunnel is up and running.
```

thats my openfortivpn connection.. and it create a new ppp0 interface

```
└─$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 649733  bytes 90673438 (86.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 649733  bytes 90673438 (86.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1354
        inet 192.168.10.20  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 169.254.2.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 111  bytes 1101 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 132  bytes 4021 (3.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a5b:d6ff:fea3:cd48  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:5b:e2:b8:ac:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1991278  bytes 1637588280 (1.5 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1471015  bytes 669954984 (638.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

route -n output.. with the xx.xx.xx.xx IP that im connecting to

```
└─$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
xx.xx.xx.xx     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
151.8.75.25     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.2.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.9.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

im able to ping google using my wlan0 interface but couldnt using ppp0 interface

```
└─$ ping -I ppp0 google.com 
PING google.com (142.250.201.46) from 192.168.10.20 ppp0: 56(84) bytes of data.
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4091ms


└─$ curl --interface wlan0 ifconfig.co
xx.xx.xx.xx
                                                                                                                                                                          
┌──(redandwhite㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ curl --interface ppp0 ifconfig.co
```

i think the idea is add two default gateways. the main idea behind the second gateway approach, is to create a second routing table..so that the routes are added and deleted whenever the vpn connection is established.. but hv no idea to do so + i dont wanna mess things up.

Comment: im asking is it even possible!

Comment: It might be possible if you follow the routing instructions in the suggested duplicate